# Concatenate along last dimension with custom layer with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to concatenate a number to the last dimension of a (None, 10, 3) tensor to make it a (None, 10, 4) tensor using a custom layer. It seems impossible, because to concatenate, all the dimensions except for the one being merged on must be equal and we can't initialize a tensor with 'None' as the first dimension.

For example, the code below gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node position_embedding_concat_37/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](Placeholder, position_embedding_concat_37/concat/values_1, position_embedding_concat_37/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,10,3], [10,1], []
```

```
    class PositionEmbeddingConcat(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
        def __init__(self, sequence_length, **kwargs):
            super(PositionEmbeddingConcat, self).__init__(**kwargs)
                    
            self.positional_embeddings_array = np.arange(sequence_length).reshape(sequence_length, 1)
            
        def call(self, inputs):
            
            outp = tf.concat([inputs, self.positional_embeddings_array], axis = 2)
            
            return outp
    
    seq_len = 10    
        
    input_layer = Input(shape = (seq_len, 3))
    
    embedding_layer = PositionEmbeddingConcat(sequence_length = seq_len)
    
    embeddings = embedding_layer(input_layer)
    
    dense_layer = Dense(units = 1)
    
    output = dense_layer(Flatten()(embeddings))
    
    modelT = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, output)
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You will have to make sure you respect the batch dimension. Maybe something like this: `outp = tf.concat([inputs, tf.cast(tf.repeat(self.positional_embeddings_array[None, ...], repeats=tf.shape(inputs)[0], axis=0), dtype=tf.float32)], axis = 2)`. Let me know if that works..

Comment: yeah, that works! I wasn't familiar with tf.cast, and I also thought that tf.shape(inputs)[0]  returned None.  Please post that as an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make sure you respect the batch dimension. Maybe something like this:

```
outp = tf.concat([inputs, tf.cast(tf.repeat(self.positional_embeddings_array[None, ...], repeats=tf.shape(inputs)[0], axis=0), dtype=tf.float32)], axis = 2)
```

Also, `tf.shape` gives you the dynamic shape of a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

your question is to concatenate of tensors shape [10, 3] and [10, 1] but you need to perform a Dense function with a specific number of units. You can remark multiplication to use tf.concatenate() only or you change the Dense function to the specific number of units.

Sample: Position embedding is not performed concatenate function, tails to the current dimension, or propagated results from both for domain result.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyPositionEmbeddedLayer( tf.keras.layers.Concatenate ):
    def __init__( self, units ):
        super(MyPositionEmbeddedLayer, self).__init__( units )
        self.num_units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_units])

    def call(self, inputs, tails):
        ### area to perform pre-calculation or custom algorithms ###
        #                                                          #
        #                                                          #
        ############################################################
        temp = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=2)([inputs, tails])
        temp = tf.matmul(temp, self.kernel)
        temp = tf.squeeze( temp )
        return temp

#####################################################
        
start = 3
limit = 93
delta = 3
sample = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.float32 )
sample = tf.constant( sample, shape=( 10, 1, 3, 1 ) )

start = 3
limit = 33
delta = 3
tails = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
tails = tf.cast( tails, dtype=tf.float32 )
tails = tf.constant( tails, shape=( 10, 1, 1, 1 ) )

layer = MyPositionEmbeddedLayer(10)

print( layer(sample, tails) )
```

Output: You see it learning with Dense kernels, close neighbors frequencies aliases.

```
 ...
 [[-26.67632     35.44779     23.239683    20.374893   -12.882696
    54.963055   -18.531412    -4.589509   -21.722694   -43.44675   ]
  [-27.629044    36.713783    24.069672    21.102568   -13.3427925
    56.92602    -19.193249    -4.7534204  -22.498507   -44.99842   ]
  [-28.58177     37.979774    24.89966     21.830242   -13.802889
    58.88899    -19.855083    -4.917331   -23.274317   -46.55009   ]
  [ -9.527256    12.6599245    8.299887     7.276747    -4.600963
    19.629663    -6.6183615   -1.6391104   -7.7581053  -15.516697  ]]], shape=(10, 4, 10), dtype=float32)
```